# Android Studio can not load so libs

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I exported ADT project for Android Studio then remove some errors, at last, my App launched on AS but this crashed soon.

```
Couldn't load icu4c from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader...
```

I remember my project has dependency with some '.so' files. Edited gradle file like that.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs/armeabi', 'libs/armeabi-v7a']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    defaultConfig {
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a"
            ldLibs "libcserver", "libtest", "libicu4c"
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is perfectly load icu4c but

```
Couldn't load icu4c from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader...
```

Do you have any idea to solve it?